# Is it possible to override the default settings for the maximum heap size for any Java applet?

Tags: java, memory-management, applet, max

I am using a piece of java software written by someone else, but it keeps running out of memory. I have tried to allocate more memory at initialisation of the program (with -Xmx), but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Is it possible that the writers of the software have hardcoded the maximum heap size, and that therefore the extra memory I'm allocating at initialisation doesn't have any effect? Or should -Xmx always work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible that the writers of the software have hardcoded the maximum heap size, and that therefore the extra memory I'm allocating at initialisation doesn't have any effect?

No.  The memory size is set before the code is loaded.

> Or should -Xmx always work?

It depends what you mean, and how you are using it.  For a long time, there was no way to assign extra memory to applets.  Around 1.5 (if memory serves) extra options were added to the applet element - one of which was for max. memory.  In the Plug-In 2 JRE architecture, applets can be launched with JWS, and can assign memory via the launch file.

Comment: The file I'm trying to increase the allocated memory for is a .jnlp file. Should -Xmx work with that as well? Because I'm currently just running it from the command line (or cmd.exe) in vista, with a -Xmx1500m flag. Or am I doing something completely wrong?

Comment: Wait, now I see what I've been doing wrong. The .jnlp is a webstart file, which already contains the -Xmx flag. By editing the flag in the .jnlp file itself I've been able to increase the amount of allocated memory. Thanks for the help!